# Convert SQL to JPQL: INNER JOIN with SELECT

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I have the following SQL statement for a really complex search for my spring boot backend. No I need to transfer this to JQPL for the search method within my repository.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dav_n.*
  FROM [DwhTest].[dbo].[DimensionAttributeValue] dav_n
  INNER JOIN [DwhTest].[dbo].[DimensionAttributeValue] dav_l on dav_n.MasterData_ID = dav_l.MasterData_ID AND dav_l.DimensionAttribute_ID = $PARAM1 AND dav_l.LstValue = $PARAMA2
        AND ((
            SELECT TOP 1 StartDate FROM DimensionAttributeValue
            WHERE MasterData_ID = dav_n.MasterData_ID AND DimensionAttribute_ID = dav_n.DimensionAttribute_ID AND StartDate <= getdate()
            ORDER BY StartDate DESC
        ) = dav_n.StartDate OR dav_n.StartDate IS NULL)
  WHERE dav_n.DimensionAttribute_ID = $PARAM3 AND dav_n.ChrValue LIKE '$PARAM4%'
```

`$PARAM1` - `$PARAM4` are my search variables. The following listing is the code of my `PagingAndSortingRepository`:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT dav_n FROM DimensionAttributeValue dav_n " +
            "INNER JOIN DimensionAttributeValue dav_l on dav_n.MasterData_ID = dav_l.MasterData_ID AND dav_l.DimensionAttribute_ID = :lstAttributeId AND dav_l.LstValue = :lstValue " +
            "AND ((SELECT TOP 1 StartDate FROM DimensionAttributeValue WHERE MasterData_ID = dav_n.MasterData_ID AND DimensionAttribute_ID = dav_n.DimensionAttribute_ID AND StartDate <= getdate() ORDER BY StartDate DESC) = dav_n.StartDate OR dav_n.StartDate IS NULL)" +
            "WHERE dav_n.DimensionAttribute_ID = :chrValueAttributeId AND dav_n.ChrValue LIKE ':chrValue%'")
    Page<DimensionAttributeValue> searchByCharValueAndFilter(
            @Param(value = "chrValueAttributeId") Long chrValueAttributeId, @Param(value = "lstAttributeId") Long lstAttributeId,
            @Param(value = "chrValue") String chrValue, @Param(value = "lstValue") Long lstValue, Pageable pageable);
```

I get an error for the `AND (([..]` statement: `'(', <expression>, FUNCTION or identifier expected, got '('`

Can anyone help me to translate this statement? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have got an `AND` and one side of the comparator within those brackets.

You need to compare the result to something or add exists:

```
AND EXISTS ((
            SELECT TOP 1 StartDate FROM DimensionAttributeValue
            WHERE MasterData_ID = dav_n.MasterData_ID 
              AND DimensionAttribute_ID = dav_n.DimensionAttribute_ID AND StartDate <= getdate()
            ORDER BY StartDate DESC
        ) = dav_n.StartDate OR dav_n.StartDate IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I still got errors. Could you correct the statement for me. I am literally lost.